# Splash Page for Master-Detail Controller Crash EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXCI386_BPT, subcode=0x0)

Tags: ipad, crash, swift, splash-screen, xcode6

(Xcode6 beta3, Swift, iPad, iOS7.1 build)

I am trying to add a splash page before a split view controller.

- Added new splash page view controller in storyboard
- Set Initial view by drag n' dropping arrow to new VC
- Wired button to segue to the master-detail view.

I am getting the following crash: `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (Code=EXCI386_BPT, subcode=0x0)'

Where did I go wrong? Supporting screen shots below. Note that in "Crashes" storyboard, the button segues to the Split View Controller. Thx. :)

### CRASHES:

[image]

### WORKS:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a scenario similar to your "crashing" version, but without the segue from the splash to the main view controller.

In the viewDidLoad I make my initializations, then I use this snippet of objective-c code to launch the main view controller:

```
UINavigationController *dashboard = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DashboardNavigationViewController"];
[self presentViewController:dashboard animated:YES completion:^{
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:dashboard];
}];
```

What I think it's missing in your case is *changing the root view controller* once it is loaded and shown. Of course if the user has to click a button to close the splash, add that code to its click handler.

If you know objective-c, you should be able to translate that snippet in swift - let me know otherwise and I'll post it here.

I hope that's the reason of your crash.